# How do I get Webpack to transpile ES6 code?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm pretty new to Webpack, and I'm just trying to get a simple project off the ground here. I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/jay/Documents/personal_projects/open_phil_grants_visualizer/index.js Unexpected token (6:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import App from './app';
| 
| ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));
| 
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./index.js
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

the dependencies in my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "d3": "^4.9.1",
  "lodash": "^4.17.4",
  "react": "^15.6.1",
  "react-d3-basic": "^1.6.11",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
}
```

Here is my `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

here is `app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <h2>
        Hello from the App component!
      </h2>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

How can I get this thing going?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're going to need to set up your loader rules to actually process and transpile your files to browser compatible ES5. Webpack does not automatically convert your ES2015 and JSX code to be web-compatible, you have to tell it to apply a [loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/) to certain files to transpile them *to web-compatible code*, as the error states. Since you don't do this, the error happens.

Assuming you have Webpack version 2+, use the `rules` property in the configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        include: 'YOUR_APP_SRC_DIR',
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This adds a rule to the Webpack config that uses the RegEx in `test` to select files that end in `.js` or `.jsx`. Then it uses `babel-loader` with the presets `es2015` and `react` to use Babel and transpile your JSX and ES2015 code to ES5 code. You will also need to install the following packages:

- `babel-core`
- `babel-loader`
- `babel-preset-react`

And you can get rid of:

- `babel-cli`

More info at the [Webpack documentation for modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/).

Comment: Note that `babel-preset-es2015` is deprecated as of Babel v6. It's now recommended to use [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env).