# Is Babel and uglify.js included by default in Webpack 4

Tags: javascript

I was learning webpack and babel and majority of tutorials on YouTube teach to install webpack and babel separately. But I tried to install webpack only without installing babel( and uglify.js). So, I used webpack then it automatically uglified and changed my ES6 code into ES5 how is that possible?. The question is Does webpack 4 use uglify.js and babel behind the scenes even if I do not install them manually?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack does not contain Babel or uglify by default. These are contained within the loaders. These are seperate npm packages you need to install used in the configuration.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742106/how-do-i-get-webpack-to-transpile-es6-code) can give you an idea of how these are configured:

In order to check yourself if a package contains another package you can easily make an empty folder and run one of the following:

```
npm install --save webpack@4
yarn add webpack@4
```

and then check the 'yarn.lock' or 'package-lock.json' file and search for the dependency.