# Confusion on the use of webpack

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning Webpack and would like to ask some questions on it. **The first question,** why to use Webpack to create one bundle out of multiple JS files if we can use ES6 import&export and use one script, that is, say, initially, we have three JS files: one.js, two.js and three.js.In HTML we use three scripts:

```
<script src="./one.js">
<script src="./two.js">
<script src="./three.js">
```

Then, we use import and export which enables us to use one script like `<script src="./one.js">` in HTML. **The second question**, why is Webpack also called transpiler? What exactly does it transpile?

Comment: If you have broken your app into hundreds of separate files (which is entirely reasonable for any non-trivial page), and they all `import` each other, then the browser has to make hundreds of separate HTTP requests to fetch them all. That's quite some overhead and will noticeably slow down the loading process.

Comment: @deceze, hey dude, thank you for your kind comments, you mean even if we include only one script in HTML and inside that JS file we use imports. Other scripts will be downloaded anyways RIght?

Comment: They *have* to be. Otherwise the browser can't execute them.

Comment: @deceze, ok, I have last question, why is Webpack also called transpiler? What exactly does it transpile? Only transpiles ES6 modules into CommonJS?

Comment: At the very least it transpiles multiple individual files into one bundled file. With additional plugins it can transpile Typescript into ES, or ES6 into ES5, or do all sorts of source transformations. It exists to turn some source code into some other source code, which is *transpiling*.

Comment: @deceze, So if I understand it correctly one would never use Babel in order to make ES6 modules running in ES5 browsers because webpack is doing this? I mean Webpack ONLY handles ES6 modules running in ES5 browsers without Babel. What do you think about that?

Comment: @Pop Webpack itself doesn't really transpile, it uses other loader modules (like Babel) to do the actual transpiling work. Here's a good summary about Babel vs Webpack's roles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742106/how-do-i-get-webpack-to-transpile-es6-code

Comment: @Joseph, thank you for your kind comments, just look at this duscussion and read comments below answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642237/does-webpack-make-es6-modules-compatible-with-es5-browsers

Comment: @Joseph, it says that Webpack is used to transpile ES6 modules without Babel

Comment: The 'yes' in the comment is misdirected. If you read the rest of the comment it contradicts it - they specifically say you'd use a combination of Webpack and a compiler in order to convert code. Webpack doesn't have the ability to do transpiling on its own, outside of a bunch of plugins that it integrates with.

Answer (score 0):

webpack does many tasks and bundling, transpile are couple of them.

1. **Bundling:** As we divide our javascript code into multiple component/classes/widget, and reuse them through out the Project. you can include all of them into index.html, that is fine but HTTP protocol will download only 2 files at a time so your initial loading time increases. However people tends to create 2 bundled files nowadays to drop initial loading time.
2. **Transpiler:** Transpiler converts some form of code to other form. As we know all browsers understand ES5 but in most of the frameworks we use high level syntax like ES^/7 so it is necessary to convert them to lower level. Webpack uses babel package to do that. that's why we call it transpilar too.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly one would never use Babel in order to make ES6 modules running in ES5 browsers because webpack is doing this? I mean Webpack ONLY handles ES6 modules running in ES5 browsers without Babel. What do you think about that?

Comment: web pack is task runner. for tasks it needs packages. for transpiler it uses a package called babel.